# Scrollbar Inside/Outside Div using CSS or any feasible way

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I try to make a website (ASP.NET) with a sidebar and topbar where the topbar have 3 row, menubar, bannerbar and dividerbar.

[image]

Only sidebar have scrollbar vertically while menubar and dividerbar should have horizontally only. This scrollbar only appear when hover and window is at certain height/width.

I manage to do just this. However, my sidebar scrollbar is INSIDE div overlapping itself, my menubar is OUTSIDE div overlapping another div and my dividerbar is INSIDE div overlapping it self.

[image]

What I want is to make that the all scrollbar is either INSIDE or OUTSIDE of div. Is there anyway to do this or it will stuck like this?

This is code for my master page

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <h1>Module</h1>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <br />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnOverallDashboard" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/OverallDashboard.png" PostBackUrl="~/OverallDashboard.aspx" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnHull" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Hull.png" PostBackUrl="~/M1-Hull/HullDashboard.aspx" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnTopside" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Topside.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnTurret" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Turret.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnRiser" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Riser.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnMooring" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Mooring.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <br />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSelectShip" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png" PostBackUrl="SelectStructure.aspx" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnHome" runat="server" Height="60px" ImageUrl="Misc/RibbonIcon/Dashboard.png" PostBackUrl="LogoutUser.aspx" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-fixed-top topbar-nav">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-fixed-top topbar-banner">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-fixed-top topbar-divider">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="page-content">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">

                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is code for my CSS

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,177,169);
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    top: 170px;    
    position: absolute
}
.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center
}
.sidebar-nav h1 {
    font-size: 14px
}
.topbar-nav {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    z-index: 1031;
}
.topbar-banner {
    background-color:rgb(235,235,235);
    top: 60px;
    height:75px
}
.topbar-divider {
    background-color:rgb(0,177,169);
    top: 135px;
    height: 35px
}
.topbar-nav,
.topbar-banner,
.topbar-divider {
    left: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.topbar-nav,
.topbar-banner {
    font-size: 0
}
.topbar-nav:hover,
.topbar-divider:hover {
    overflow-x: auto
}
.page-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 61px
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 61px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper:hover {
        overflow-y: auto
    }
    
    #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative
    }

    .topbar-nav,
    .topbar-banner,
    .topbar-divider {
        left: 61px
    }
}
```